# How to add a list item of different type

Tags: usability, lists

I'm  working on a list containing expandable items that have properties and actions.

Every list item can have 6 different types.

Currently, at the bottom of the list there are 6 different add new item buttons(+) that correspond to the different list item types.

What do you think is the best way to organise the add new buttons?

Thank you all in advance.

[image]

Comment: What do these list items and item types represent? If you're able to provide us with more context, it might be easier for us to generate solutions.

Comment: Hi, each list item is a rule that consists of one or more parameters. So we have 6 rule types that can be added up in a list with various combinations.

Comment: What is the user goal in this UI fragment? E.g. to work with the items, and sometimes to add new ones, or to build the items list, or... Anyway, it looks like choosing the right item type can create excessive cognitive load. I'd try to make first step easy, like ADD ITEM, and then make all the setup within the newly created item as a second step.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, user objective is to both work in the items and form a combination of the different list items that stack up together. Having 6 choises barely needs a two click action ( drop-down etc ). That's one of the primary concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menandros, my suggestion is to make the UI less cluttered, and make the item type selection process more easy.

The flow is:

1. User selects ADD ITEM
2. System creates an item and proposes to select item's type
3. User scans the list from top to down and selects the right type
4. System displays attributes for the selected item type (not shown in the pic below)

[image]

Pro:

1. The UI is less cluttered (usability heuristic of clean UI)
2. Item types are shown only in the context of the item creation, it's just a right place for this (the principle of information disclosure)
3. Item types are easy to scan, in a single direction, from top to down (increase selection speed)

Hope this helped )

Comment: Thanks Alexey, 
that was very helpful. I will share the outcome of the usability tests.